# PnP to update new SharePoint Subsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, pnp-powershell, sub-site

We are using the following script due to the SharePoint REST API not controlling these properties.
When I run this below script as a whole, I get:

```
Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The web being updated was changed by an external process."
At line:41 char:1
+ $web.Context.ExecuteQuery()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServerException
```

If I re-run the last 4 lines it works though:

```
$web.MembersCanShare = $false
$web.SetUseAccessRequestDefaultAndUpdate($true)
$web.Update()
$web.Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

## Entire script is below:

```
$varURL = Read-Host -Prompt 'Provide URL to site'
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $varURL
#Set all your variables
$web = Get-PnPWeb -Includes Title
$OwnersGroup = $web.Title.substring($web.Title.IndexOf(' | ')+3)+' Owners'
$MembersGroup = $web.Title.substring($web.Title.IndexOf(' | ')+3)+' Members'
$MembersEXTERNALGroup = $web.Title.substring($web.Title.IndexOf(' | ')+3)+' Members EXTERNAL'
$VisitorsGroup = $web.Title.substring($web.Title.IndexOf(' | ')+3)+' Visitors'
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $OwnersGroup -SetAssociatedGroup Owners
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $MembersGroup -SetAssociatedGroup Members
#Associate default Owners to Members/MembersExternal/Owners/Visitors Groups -Owner $OwnersGroup
#Turn off editing -AllowMembersEditMembership $false
#Let everyone see membership -OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership $false
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $MembersGroup -Owner $OwnersGroup
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $MembersGroup -AllowMembersEditMembership $false
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $MembersGroup -OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership $false
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $MembersEXTERNALGroup -Owner $OwnersGroup
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $MembersEXTERNALGroup -AllowMembersEditMembership $false
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $MembersEXTERNALGroup -OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership $false
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $OwnersGroup -Owner $OwnersGroup
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $OwnersGroup -AllowMembersEditMembership $false
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $OwnersGroup -OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership $false
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $VisitorsGroup -Owner $OwnersGroup
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $VisitorsGroup -AllowMembersEditMembership $false
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $VisitorsGroup -OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership $false
#Make sure members can't share nor edit member group
$web = Get-PnPWeb
#-Includes MembersCanShare, AssociatedMemberGroup.AllowMembersEditMembership
$web.MembersCanShare = $false
$web.SetUseAccessRequestDefaultAndUpdate($true)
$web.Update()
$web.Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `$web.Context.ExecuteQuery()` before 2nd `$web = Get-PnPWeb` in your code. complete script will be like below:

```
$varURL = Read-Host -Prompt 'Provide URL to site'
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $varURL
#Set all your variables
$web = Get-PnPWeb -Includes Title
$OwnersGroup = $web.Title.substring($web.Title.IndexOf(' | ')+3)+' Owners'
$MembersGroup = $web.Title.substring($web.Title.IndexOf(' | ')+3)+' Members'
$MembersEXTERNALGroup = $web.Title.substring($web.Title.IndexOf(' | ')+3)+' Members EXTERNAL'
$VisitorsGroup = $web.Title.substring($web.Title.IndexOf(' | ')+3)+' Visitors'
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $OwnersGroup -SetAssociatedGroup Owners
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $MembersGroup -SetAssociatedGroup Members
#Associate default Owners to Members/MembersExternal/Owners/Visitors Groups -Owner $OwnersGroup
#Turn off editing -AllowMembersEditMembership $false
#Let everyone see membership -OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership $false
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $MembersGroup -Owner $OwnersGroup
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $MembersGroup -AllowMembersEditMembership $false
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $MembersGroup -OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership $false
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $MembersEXTERNALGroup -Owner $OwnersGroup
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $MembersEXTERNALGroup -AllowMembersEditMembership $false
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $MembersEXTERNALGroup -OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership $false
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $OwnersGroup -Owner $OwnersGroup
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $OwnersGroup -AllowMembersEditMembership $false
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $OwnersGroup -OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership $false
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $VisitorsGroup -Owner $OwnersGroup
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $VisitorsGroup -AllowMembersEditMembership $false
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $VisitorsGroup -OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership $false
#Make sure members can't share nor edit member group

#I have added this line here
$web.Context.ExecuteQuery()

$web = Get-PnPWeb
#-Includes MembersCanShare, AssociatedMemberGroup.AllowMembersEditMembership
$web.MembersCanShare = $false
$web.SetUseAccessRequestDefaultAndUpdate($true)
$web.Update()
$web.Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: Just tried, and get error due to last line #43: $web.Context.ExecuteQuery()

Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The web being updated was changed by an external process."
At line:43 char:1
+ $web.Context.ExecuteQuery()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServerException